# C# MySql Storing an arraylist in the database

Tags: c#, mysql, arraylist

I have an mysql database in which I am storing details of a project. One of these details is the staff associated with the project. In the project table I have a column for staff in the project. In my c# code behind I am storing it in an arraylist. I am wondering is there any way to store that arraylist in a single column in the database?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't store bunch of entities in a single column.

You'd better create another table and link your first one with second one through relation table.

```
TableA: id | name
TableB: id | bla
TableRelations: tableA_id | tableB_id
```

It is called `many-to-many` relation (`N:M` as a shorthand)

[First random link from google related to many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php)

Comment: I answered to the OP about the ability to serialize the ArrayList and store in a VARCHAR field. Although possible, I even fully indicate your answer as correct. It always important to use the relational model like it's supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

Generally storing multiples values in column is an indication of poor database design. It makes it very difficult to efficiently select rows based on criteria within that single column. Having said that, if you really only ever need to select those values on a per row basis then consider using XML

[Using XML with MySQL](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/mysql-xml.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should certainly follow the concept of many-to-many for this, like pointed by @zerkms. But if you is really interested in saving the `ArrayList` into a *single field*, you can **serialize this `ArrayList` to `String` and store in a `VARCHAR` field**.

About *serializing ArrayList to String*, you can view some suggested ways in this topic: [Dynamically create javascript array with c# code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918302/dynamically-create-javascript-array-with-c-code-behind).

Remember that you'll need to *deserialize* when reading back to your application too.