# Passing vars from C# to Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am a beginner when it comes to passing around different vars in C#, ASP.NET.
In my application I am using C#, ASP.NET and SQL Server. I have to write some Javascript but I can't figure out how to pass the value I have in the code page of an ASP page (C#) to a JavaScript Var.

So for exmaple in my aspx.cs page I will have a list of numbers that I want to be stored in a Javascrip var.

```
 public List<int> listNumbers = new List<int>(new int[] { 10, 30, 50, 70 });
```

When I hard code the values myself, the Javascript does perform its function so I know the issue is the way I'm passing it. The hardcoded values are...

```
var dataArray = [5, 40, 50, 60];
```

I have tried to pass it along with something like this but didn't have much luck (but thought it would be worth sharing)

```
 var dataArray =('<%=listNumbers%>');
```

The goal is to pass the values from the C# page to the ASP page  section where I can store them in a JS var.

Hope this explains enough and thank you for any suggestions everyone! :)

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918302/dynamically-create-javascript-array-with-c-sharp-code-behind help?

Comment: As a tip, if you simply want to print a comma-separated list of integers to the output, you can use `<%=string.Join(", ", dataArray)%>`. Check the [string.Join(string, IEnumerable<T>)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join#System_String_Join__1_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) overload.

Comment: Thanks mjwills, that fixed it! and thanks for the top Vinicius